# Set statement error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am receiving the 3075 error (invalid operator) from the script below. The VBA error is marking the set statement in yellow. I don't understand why. What is lacking?

```
strSql = "SELECT FA_AVG.RadNr, (Left([Text],122)) AS LetaEfter1, Mid([Text],130,18) AS LetaEfter2, Right(Left([Text],184),36) AS LetaEfter3, FA_AVG.PerNr, FA_AVG.Fil, FA_AVG.GR1 " & _
"FROM FA_AVG " & _
"WHERE (((FA_AVG.RadNr)=20) AND ((Left([Text],122))='" & strTemp1 & "') AND ((Right(Left([Text],184),36))='" & strTemp3 & "') AND (Trim(FA_AVG.PerNr)='" & strPer & "'))"

Set rstAddData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
```

Comment: What is [Text]?  Is that a column in the table FA_AVG or some textbox control?  You also may want to format your code using the code snippet tools provided by SO for readability.

Comment: Also what are the values of strTemp1, strTemp3 and strPer?  They shouldn't have apostrophes or any non-alpha character that can break your built sql.

Answer (score 0):

Run this and study the output, and it will probably be quite clear to you why it won't run:

```
strSql = "SELECT FA_AVG.RadNr, (Left([Text],122)) AS LetaEfter1, Mid([Text],130,18) AS LetaEfter2, Right(Left([Text],184),36) AS LetaEfter3, FA_AVG.PerNr, FA_AVG.Fil, FA_AVG.GR1 " & _
"FROM FA_AVG " & _
"WHERE (((FA_AVG.RadNr)=20) AND ((Left([Text],122))='" & strTemp1 & "') AND ((Right(Left([Text],184),36))='" & strTemp3 & "') AND (Trim(FA_AVG.PerNr)='" & strPer & "'))"

Debug.Print strSQL
```